# Azure API Management returns an InternalServerError while PUT'ing a Swagger definition

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I'm trying to import a Swagger definition via Azure API Managment's REST API following the steps on [this blog](https://www.codit.eu/blog/2016/01/25/deploy-your-swagger-api-to-azure-api-management-automatically/) and the [reference documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn781423.aspx#ImportExisting). However, I'm getting a 500 error in response, with the body:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InternalServerError",
    "message": "Request processing failed due to internal error.",
    "details": null
  }
}
```

My request works for a GET, but not for a PUT. Can anyone point out what's wrong with my request or potential setup issues I should look into?

This is the request I'm sending:

```
PUT /apis/{app-id}?api-version=2014-02-14-preview&amp;import=true HTTP/1.1
Host: {tenant}.management.azure-api.net
Authorization: SharedAccessSignature uid={uid}&ex={ex}&sn={sn}
Content-Type: application/vnd.swagger.link+json
If-Match: *
Cache-Control: no-cache    
{
    "link": "{app}.cloudapp.azure.com:8165/swagger/docs/0"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"link" value should contain schema, i.e. start with "http://" or "https://". We'll address this issue to provide more meaningful error message.

Comment: U_U *headdesk*
Thank you so much